# Ruby on Rails: invalid argument to TimeZone[]: nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone, activesupport

**NOTE:** This is my first post, so please be kind.  I'm a rails newb so it's very plausible that i'm missing something simple.

I'm working with a Ruby on Rails application locally and am getting this ArgumentError when attempting to fill out a test form:

```
invalid argument to TimeZone[]: nil
```

Application Trace shows the following:

```
app/models/venue.rb:117:in `timezone'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:80:in `block in create'
```

Lines 116-118 in venue.rb:

```
def timezone
 ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(timezone_name)
end
```

Lines 78-87 in events_controller.rb:

```
["start", "end"].each do |t|
     month, day, year = params["event"]["#{ t }_date"].split("/")
     @event.send("#{ t }s_at=", @event.venue.timezone.local_to_utc(Time.utc(
        ("20" + year).to_i, 
        month.to_i, 
        day.to_i,
        military_hours(t),
        params["#{ t }_minute"].to_i,
        0
     )))
```

The form works correctly on the live site, so its possible that i setup my dev environment improperly.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

```
  class Venue
      key :timezone_name, String

  def set_timezone_name
     tz = Timezone.contains(self)
     self.timezone_name = tz.name if tz
  end
```

Comment: `timezone_name` is null is one of the `venue` objects. What is the code for `timezone_name`? It is a method of variable?

Comment: Hello Rajesh, thanks for replying.  Editing my original post to address your question

Comment: Which code is responsible for setting the value of `timezone_name`?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you provided more context for this question. I'll assume that `set_timezone_name` is called to initialize the `timezone_name` value when there is none set.  It's then likely in this case `set_timezone_name` fails to set a value. You could try providing a fallback to guarantee a value is set. Example:

```
def set_timezone_name
  tz = Timezone.contains(self)
  self.timezone_name = tz.try(:name) || “Eastern Time (US & Canada)”
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the lack of context.  This is a new experience for me!  You are correct in your assumptions, however the solution you provided didn't resolve the problem.